# Java Serialization, Why no Serialization Exception when saving into DB?

Tags: java, serialization

While saving a pojo class (annotated with `@Entity` and `@Table` in springBoot, JPA) into a database, the class is saved despite the fact it does not implement the `Serializable` interface.

However, if I try to save a normal class to a text file, I get a `NotSerializableException`. I understand that trying to serializable the class means writing the state of the object into the file using `FileOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream.write(Object)` method.

**My question:** Why I am not getting a `NotSerializableException` when I try to save the same class into my database?

Comment: [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/serialization/custom-serialization-readobject-writeobject/) might help

Comment: I understand English is not your first language. But PLEASE, make at least several sentences. Consider using formatting to emphasize on the errors you are getting. As it stands, your logorrhea is going to turn off a lot of people who may be able to answer.

Comment: Try this one: Employee implements Serializable

Answer (score 2):

The word "serialize" is overused, which can be confusing.

It is *generally* used to describe the conversion of a Java class instance to some storage/transmission format, binary or text, e.g.

- We can serialize to XML text using JAXB. This requires some use of `@Xml...` annotations, e.g. at lease one class must have `@XmlRootElement`.
- We can serialize to JSON text using some JSON library. Annotations like `@Json...` can optionally be used.
- We can serialize to a database using JPA/Hibernate. This requires an `@Entity` annotation.
- We can serialize to a binary file using an [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html). This requires the class to implement [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).
- ... and other ways ...

Only serializing to a binary file using an `ObjectOutputStream` will throw [`NotSerializableException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html).

The others throw different kinds of exceptions, and uses different mechanisms to customize the serialization process, e.g. `@XmlElement` annotations for JAXB, `@JsonProperty` annotations for JSON, `@Column` annotations for JPA, etc.

You can use all 4 at the same time on a class, if needed, since they are non-overlapping.

Short answer is that only serialization using an `ObjectOutputStream` requires `Serializable`, so you don't need to implement `Serializable`, if you're not serializing to a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize POJOs annotated with `@Entity`, you need to implement the `Serializable` interface. `@Entity` does not make POJOs serializable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are not getting a `NotSerializableException` when saving the `Employee` to the database is that the database binding is not using Java Object Serialization.   Instead, it is using JPA and an Object Relational Mapping (ORM) to map the fields of the `Employee` onto columns in a table in a relational database schema.

`Serializable` and `NotSerializableException` are only relevant to programs that use Java Object Sereialization via `ObjectInputStream` and/or `ObjectInputStream` or something like RMI.

If that doesn't make sense to you, you should probably read a tutorial on Hibernate (or whatever ORM implementation you are using).